# synchronization without locks

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, gcc

I am thinking of using below mechanism to synchronize two/more threads. Only drawback I think is CPU usage. Please share your comments on this mechanism. Are there any problems with this implementation ? (assume gcc's _*sync** functions are portable )

```
//logic is that if lock = 1 means a thread has acquired the lock.
//                 lock = 0 means lock is free.
// acquireLock:
//        add 1 to lock if value is 1 this thread gets the lock
//        if value is > 1 mean some one else have taken the lock, so decrement the count


int lock = 0 ; // global variable.


void acquireLock()
{

    while(__sync_add_and_fetch (&lock,1) > 1)
    {
        __sync_add_and_fetch (&lock,-1);
    }

}

void releaseLock()
{
     __sync_add_and_fetch (&lock,-1);
}
```

So any thread that wants to access a shared or global data would first call acquireLock, access the global data and then releaseLock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are implementing a kind of spin lock. Instead of incrementing and decrementing, you can use a CAS loop instead:

```
void acquireLock () {
    while (!_sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&lock, 0, 1)) {}
}

void releaseLock () {
    int unlock_success = _sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&lock, 1, 0);
    assert(unlock_success);
}
```

The compare and swap will check to see if the variable contents match the expected value (the second parameter). If it does, it will set the variable to the new value (the third parameter). If the expected value does not match, then the call fails. This is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

What [@jxh suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355878/1246009) is a good solution. However, since you also asked what could be wrong with your solution, here's my take:

You are splitting the "lock acquisition failure" into two steps:

1. Try acquiring the lock (increment the flag)
2. Backup if failed (decrement the flag)

So even if a thread fails to acquire the lock, it still modifies the global state (increment) only to fix this modification later, at another time. The issue is that there is no guarantee that the "fix" will happen immediately, soon, or if at all. The increment and decrement are atomic within themselves but not as a couple.

Basically, if some thread tries to acquire the lock and fails, there is a chance that it may not be able to decrement the counter right away (thread can be swapped out). Now, even if the current lock holder releases the lock, other threads cannot acquire the lock anymore, because the value will always be greater than 1 (that is, until the "sleeper" comes back on and does a decrement). This either creates a bottleneck (all threads depend on all "failed" threads to do their decrements) or a deadlock (if a "failed" thread increments and dies for whatever reason).

This won't happen with @jxh's solution since the lock acquisition (whether it fails or succeeds) is an atomic step as a whole.